# Jenkins - What's the difference between lastFailedBuild vs lastUnstableBuild vs lastUnSuccessfulBuild?

Tags: jenkins

What's the difference between lastFailedBuild vs lastUnstableBuild vs lastUnSuccessfulBuild in Jenkins?

Answer (score 5):

To boil it down from the [Jenkins terminology](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Terminology) page which is not very clear.

**lastFailedBuild** - last time/link that compilation failed during the build, see below.

**lastUnstableBuild** - last time/link that tests failed during the build, see below.

**lastUnsuccessfulBuild** - ambiguous, see below.

**Note:** plugins can change the build states as well.

---

**Unstable build** - A build is unstable if it was built successfully and one or more publishers report it unstable. For example if the JUnit publisher is configured and a test fails then the build will be marked unstable.

**Broken/Failed build** - Build that failed during compilation.

**Unsuccessful Build** - Amibiguous, could mean both unstable and failed or just one of those.

---

Update: Jenkins now defines a new set of [terminology](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/glossary/#build-status) which fails to mention any of these.

Answer (score 0):

lastFailedBuild - When a build fails (Red ball).

lastUnstablesBuild - When a build is not stable (Yellow ball).

lastUnSuccessfulBuild - When any of the above occurs. (I'm not sure)